# Issue in comparing token contract address and address(0) in Solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to compare the token contract address with the address(0). This was working fine in older version of truffle and solidity compiler (0.4.24). When I upgraded truffle and started using the latest truffle and compiler version (0.5.0) I am unable to compare the token contract address and address(0).

Could you please assist me to resolve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Solidity 0.5.X, contract types do not include the `address` members. Per the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements):

> Contract types do not include `address` members anymore in order to
>   separate the namespaces. Therefore, it is now necessary to explicitly
>   convert values of contract type to addresses before using an `address`
>   member. Example: if `c` is a contract, change `c.transfer(...)` to
>   `address(c).transfer(...)`, and `c.balance` to `address(c).balance`.

So you will need to update that particular line of code to be `require(address(token) != address(0));`, as shown in this [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);    

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);    
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);    
}

contract init {        
    ERC20Interface token;

    function test() public view {    
        require(address(token) != address(0));
    }
}
```